# Testing that you are not a robot

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I am always coming onto this website and posting to peoples answers but half the time I have to do a test to make sure I am not a robot. And with my slow internet it takes a long time. How can I either prevent having this happen to me or could there be a better way of making sure that I am not a robot.

Comment: Probably related question on Meta Stack Overflow: [CloudFlare is ruining Stack Overflow for me with its recaptcha](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323537/cloudflare-is-ruining-stack-overflow-for-me-with-its-recaptcha)

Comment: ^ That question suggests it does not happen with direct hits but with Google search results, is that the case for you too? If so, maybe give a HTTP referer header hiding extension a try. Here's one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smart-referer/

Comment: I have starred this question for the title alone.

Comment: Are you logged in when this happens?  If so, is your account registered or unregistered?

Comment: honestly 500+ rep should exempt you from most triggers which are circumstantial (such as writing your answer in an external editor then pasting it in)

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the ways they try to prevent abuse. There are certain "suspicious" behaviors which seem to trigger it.

I have tripped it a number of times in the past. While there are a number of reasons why this may happen, I think that my habit of leaving composing a question and letting it stew for several days, if not *weeks* before posting is why I get it so much.

I'm OK with waiting a few seconds and clicking the checkbox. I think it's worthwhile to have these measures in place if they prevent some abuse.

At least you haven't gotten the teapot:

[image: Error I'm a teapot]

Comment: I think maybe that's why I always get a captcha when I post an answer on Code Review.  I always compose the review in a separate editor, and then paste and post.

Comment: I do not mind doing the whole thing either but I have some slow internet so it takes a while for the pictures to load and stuff.